# Use threads to speed up slow initialization of context manager

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, contextmanager

I am consuming from a python2.7 module which I cannot easily change. This module has a factory for a class that is a context manager. This works great for managing the lifetime of the object, but initializing this class involves waiting on creation of a cloud based resource and it can take many minutes to run. Within the scope of my program I need to create two of the objects such as the following:

```py
import immutable_module

cloud_resource_name1 = "load_ai_model"
cloud_resource_name2 = "create_input_output_model"

with immutable_module.create_remote_cloud_resource(cloud_resource_name1) as a, \
     immutable_module.create_remote_cloud_resource(cloud_resource_name2) as b: 
    result = __do_imporant_thing(a, b)

print(result)
```

**Is there a way call these two contextmanagers concurrently using threads to speed up the load time?**

Comment: It depends.  Multithreading in Python is ONLY a gain if the operations are I/O bound.  Unless the tasks wait for I/O much of the time, threading won't help at all.  However, it's easy to try it and see -- probably quicker than waiting for a response from SO.

Comment: The parsing is the bottle neck, not the IO.

Comment: Then threading would only introduce overhead with no gain…

Comment: Not in Python Python has the "global interpreter lock", which means that only one thread at a time can be executing Python code.  Running two CPU-bound Python threads takes just as long as running them sequentially.

Comment: I see, please ignore my comment then. This is toy example, and I didn't think the implementation of why the function takes a long time mattered to the question. I'll update the question to it is clear that there is an improvement from threading.

Comment: Can you wrap the remote resource initialization in your own context manager?  Something like `with my_helper_make_many_cloud_resources(*cloud_res_names) as clouds:...` ?  Where your `__enter__` routine throws the arguments into a threat pool or concurrent futures executor, and your `__exit__` does the right thing?  It'll at least conceal the roughness of calling the library's context manager protocol routines directly.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research I found a solution, but it may not be the best answer. The solution relies on calling `__enter__` and `__exit__` manually for the contextmanager.

```py
import immutable_module

cloud_resource_name1 = "load_ai_model"
cloud_resource_name2 = "create_input_output_model"

a_context = immutable_module.create_remote_cloud_resource(cloud_resource_name1) 
b_context = immutable_module.create_remote_cloud_resource(cloud_resource_name2)

a = None
b = None

try:
    def __set_a():
      global a
      a = a_context.__enter__()

    def __set_b():
      global b
      b = b_context.__enter__()

    a_thread = Thread(target=__set_a)
    b_thread = Thread(target=__set_b)

    a_thread.start()
    b_thread.start()

    a_thread.join()
    b_thread.join()

    result = __do_imporant_thing(a, b)

finally:
    try:
        if a is not None:
            a_context.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
    finally:
        if b is not None:
            b_context.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())

print(result)
```

This is really dirty, not generic at all, and there are potential issues with exception handling, but it works.

Comment: I think you forgot to put `global a` and `global b` in your helper methods; as written, it sets the local variables `a` and `b`. I *think* you've handled the problems with ensuring deterministic cleanup (which is impressive; I wouldn't want to try to parallelize something that needed context management like this), but yeah, dirty and non-generic is right.